# wpf align 2 controls

Tags: c#, wpf, text, alignment

i would like to have a textblock and texbox content one beside one.

```
                    <TextBlock  >ID: 
    <TextBox IsReadOnly="True" FontSize="25" Name="Pass"
     BorderThickness="0" Foreground="Orange"  
     Background="Transparent" 
    />
                    </TextBlock>
```

it actually works but they dont really in the same line. the texblock text(in this case `ID` is a little down and not actually in the same line.
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Like below,

```
<StackPanel Margin="5" Orientation="Horizontal">
    <TextBlock  Text="ID: "/>    
    <TextBox IsReadOnly="True" FontSize="25" Name="Pass"     BorderThickness="0" Foreground="Orange" Background="Transparent"     />
</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you putting the textbox in the textblock?  If you make them separate items, you can then place them however you want.  But if you really want to do it in the textblock, I believe you can create a template and use that to align the controls.

Comment: I would have if you had included the layout information (grid, stackpanel, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

This is what you are looking for

```
 <TextBlock  Text="ID: "></TextBlock>
<TextBox IsReadOnly="True" FontSize="25" Name="Pass"     BorderThickness="0" Foreground="Orange" Background="Transparent"     />
```